# Keras LSTM VAE invalid output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to implement LSTM based VAE.
Input shape is (sample_number, 96, 24)
And I want to have a model's output shape as (24)

```
# encoder
latent_dim = 24
inter_dim = 32
timesteps, features = 96, 24

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
    batch_size = tf.shape(z_mean)[0] # <================
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0., stddev=1.)
    return z_mean + z_log_sigma * epsilon

# timesteps, features
input_x = Input(shape= (timesteps, features)) 

#intermediate dimension 
h = LSTM(inter_dim)(input_x)


#z_layer
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
z_log_sigma = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
z = Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_sigma])

# Reconstruction decoder
decoder1 = RepeatVector(timesteps)(z)
decoder1 = LSTM(inter_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoder1)
decoder1 = Dense(features)(decoder1)


output = (Dense(24, activation='softmax'))(decoder1)


def vae_loss2(input_x, decoder1, z_log_sigma, z_mean):
    """ Calculate loss = reconstruction loss + KL loss for each data in minibatch """
    # E[log P(X|z)]
    recon = K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(input_x, decoder1))
    # D_KL(Q(z|X) || P(z|X)); calculate in closed form as both dist. are Gaussian
    kl = 0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(z_log_sigma) + K.square(z_mean) - 1. - z_log_sigma)

    return recon + kl

m = Model(input_x, output)
m.add_loss(vae_loss2(input_x, decoder1, z_log_sigma, z_mean)) #<===========
m.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the code so far, but how do I set this model so it can have 24 with `softmax` activation at the end of it?

Comment: You could just set `return_sequences=False` in your LSTM. But a VAE should usually act like an autoencoder --> input.shape == output.shape

Comment: @AloneTogether Then, it complains about the dimension :(

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: @AloneTogether It seems this is related to the loss function. ```Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_29/tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy_28/mul:
In[0] model_29/Cast (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py:671) 
In[1] model_29/tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy_28/Log:```

Comment: What is your use case for your model ? What are you trying to do? Text?

Comment: @AloneTogether Yes, it is a text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63991580/10375049

Answer (score 2):

If you are training a text VAE, you can maybe try using a `TimeDistributed` layer like this:

```py
decoder1 = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(timesteps)(z)
decoder1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(inter_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoder1)
output =  tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='linear'))(decoder1)
```

and in your loss function use `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`:

```
def vae_loss2(input_x, output, z_log_sigma, z_mean):

    cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    recon = cross_entropy(input_x, output))

    kl = 0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(z_log_sigma) + K.square(z_mean) - 1. - z_log_sigma)

    return recon + kl

m = Model(input_x, output)
m.add_loss(vae_loss2(input_x, output, z_log_sigma, z_mean))
m.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The `TimeDistributed` layer simply applies a `Dense` layer with a softmax activation function to each time step in the sequence coming from the `LSTM` layer.

Comment: Thank you for the kind response. However, I am getting this error: ```File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 4994, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 24) and (None, 96, 24) are incompatible```
Is this because `input_x` is (None, 96, 24) and `output` is (None, 24)?

Comment: Yes make sure that you set `return_sequences=True`.

Comment: I checked ```decoder1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(inter_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoder1)``` this but it still gives me the same error.. 
```input_9 (InputLayer)           [(None, 96, 24)]     0           [] ```
```output_layer (TimeDistributed)  (None, 96, 24)      792         ['lstm_17[0][0]']  ```
These are from `m.summary()`. Their dimensions looks same but not sure why it is throwing the error.

Comment: what is the shape of your data? And did you make sure **not** to add another loss function to you model when calling `model.compile`? It should just be `m.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`